# How to make substitution independent of 'gdefault'?

Tags: vim

I'm writing a small Vim script. Depending on the option *gdefault*, the substitution either needs to contain */g* or it does not.

How to make the substitution independent, regardless of the user's setting?

Apart from testing for gdefault, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but typical way to do something like this is to save the use'rs' option setting, change option to what you want, execute command, then restore user's setting.  E.g.,

```
let user_gdefault = &gdefault
set nogdefault
s/something/something else/g
let &gdefault = user_gdefault
```

If you want to do it even better use a try/finally structure:

```
let user_gdefault = &gdefault
try
    set nogdefault
    s/something/something else/g
finally    
    let &gdefault = user_gdefault
endtry
```

Comment: You got the meaning right. Basically, I was inquiring whether there was a way to make the substitution act (like gdefault was on)/(off) all the time, without having to inquire about it separely. (analogy: comparison operators ==, ==#, ==? <- something in that sense)

Comment: Another way: `execute 's/somthing/somethingelse/' . (&gdefault ? 'g' : '')`

Comment: @tungd - Certanly better! Nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make substitution independent of gdefault is to use the substitute() function instead.

For example:

```
call setline('.', substitute(getline('.'), 'something', 'somethingelse', 'g'))
```

The substitute() function is independent of gdefault. Pattern matching in this function always behaves as if the magic option is set and cpoptions is empty. However, it still obeys ignorecase.